# How to use xcAssets slicing in xCode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, uinavigationbar, xcasset

I am wondering how to use slicing in xCassets to minimize the number of resources for UINavigationBar.

I set up a normal one (320x64) and a retina one (640x128) with a logo in the very center and a solid background color. With appropriate stretching, this two ones should be enough to fit also iPad width, iOS6 and iOS7 variations, etc.

I would like the center logo not to be stretchable and everything around to be so in order for the image to work for non iOS7 nav bar (320x44 & 640x88), for iPad (width 768 px and 1536 for retina).

Using the slicing option, I tried to define different window ... any one helped me to achieve my goals and I think this is not very well documented.

Comment: please read this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html

Comment: Thanks Nithin, I already red this but it looks it not working in my case :(